# Connecting Pouch DB to mssql

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I need to connect my pouchdb, ionic, cordova, angular app to another db, which works with mvc/.net and mssql server.

In my app my constants are.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('emInspectionsApp.constants').constant('AppConstants', {
AppName:                'Inspectus',
Build:                  '', // This value is taken from config.xml, the one  defined here is overwritten
WebServicesURL:         'https://localhost:44302/api/',
WebServicesURLHTTPS:    'https://localhost:44302/api/',
LocalDatabaseName:      'CBRE_Opus_Local',
MaxPhotosPerQuestion:   4,
MaxPhotosForInspection: 40,
//maximum size of images in bytes.
//If the size of current uploaded images will be greater than this value, it will not allow to upload any other images
MaxPhotosSizeForInspection: 5000000,
// DatabaseVersion property is incremented every time a change is made to the database that
// requires a recreation of its structure
DatabaseVersion:        '1.27.1'
});
```

and my connection to db is

```
db = new PouchDB(AppConstants.LocalDatabaseName, {adapter: 'websql'});
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the issue you are having?

Comment: My mobile app syncs with my api written in .net, so now I cant connect of my mobile app , to.net api-s db.

Comment: Are you trying to sync a local database to a remote database? I'm just trying to be certain what it is you're trying to accomplish. Is there any reason you're not using CouchDB or similar on the backend?

Comment: I need to host my MSSQL Db, for mobile part of my web app, which works with PouchDb, Ionic and Cordova.

Comment: Then you'll have to write a web service that sits in front of your MSSQL Database on a web server. Your app would then communicate with that web service, which would then communicate with your database. Neither Cordova nor PouchDB have any mechanisms for communicating directly with MSSQL -- nor would you want them to, as exposing your database directly to the Internet is a very bad idea. Also make sure that your webservice provides only domain-specific APIs -- that is, I shouldn't be able to run arbitrary SQL against your database via the webservice. Instead it should only do specific things.

Comment: I also have that api, but i can't understand how to connect that api to my cordova application, can you show how to connect cordova app to API.What should I enter in place of database name to connect to that api? My example is in the question.